# iOS CSS animation flicker

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Has anybody experienced flicker effect like this?

[image]

I use Angular with `ngAnimate` module. Without `ngAnimate` there is no flicker but also other needed animations goes away. So I need to stay with `ngAnimate` but get rid of flicker.

Initial state of popup:

```
.fade-scale {   
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
  opacity:0; 
}
```

On tap it adds this class on popup

```
.show {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  opacity:1;      
}
```

All of these don't help

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2946748/645956)?

Comment: How about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22372874/645956)?

Comment: @grc also tried but w/o any luck

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4225) might be the problem. Any chance you can do it in pure css?